# Jquery Countdown Showing NaN in Safari, Works fine in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime, jquery-countdown

I am creating a penny auction site and I have several auctions on the home page. Each auction gets its own timer based on a date from the mysql date format, which is in format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

The code works fine and the timers all start counting down perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari the number shows NaN:NaN:NaN

Here's my function, its using the [jquery countdown plugin by Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html):

```
function updateTimers() {
        $( ".il-timer" ).each(function( index ) {

            var timer = $(this);
           var end_date = $(timer).attr('data-end-date');
           var auction_id = $(timer).attr('data-auction-id');

           var end = new Date(Date.parse(end_date,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"));

          $('#auction_listing_timer_'+auction_id).countdown({until: end, format: 'HMS', compact: true, description: ''});

          //Do it every 10 seconds...
            setTimeout(function(){

                updateTimers();

            }, 10000);

        });
    };
```

Comment: it looks like your `end_date` is not a valid ISO format string, as non-ISO format strings `may or may not result in NaN` -> [`.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). note- `.parse()` does not take a second parameter for your format. You can find ISO valid formats at http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: In my case I've had this date format "2020-12-31 00:00:00" stored in this variable "inlineDate". I've did a string replace for "-" with "/" using inlineDate = inlineDate.replace(/\-/g, "/"); and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few things:

- The `Date.parse` function does not take a second parameter.  The value `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"` you're passing is being ignored.
- Date parsing in JavaScript is implementation dependent.  Firefox chooses not to parse values in that particular format.
- `new Date(Date.parse(...))` is redundant.  You can just pass the string to the date constructor.
- A quick fix would be to replace the dashes with slashes before parsing:

  ```
  var end = new Date(end_date.replace(/-/g, '/'));
  ```
- A better approach would be to use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), so you *can* control the format used for parsing:

  ```
  var end = moment(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toDate();
  ```

Comment: Excellent answer. I appreciate it. All working in all browsers. A++

Comment: Possibly useful/enlightening link regarding the second point: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html .